# Repeating Samples and Adding them to a Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, sample

I have a list of names. I am trying to take repeated ($n = 1000$) samples from the names, and add them to a dataframe in R.

```
names <- c("A", "B", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")
df <- data.frame(names)

for(i in 1:1000) {
  output <- sample(names, size = 10, replace = F)
  df <- mutate(df, output)
}
```

Unfortunately, I only get one of the output columns instead of 1000. What could I do to fix this?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: If you want 1000 columns you would do `as.data.frame(replicate(1000, sample(names)))`. If you want a single column, it's `c(replicate(1000, sample(names)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use `cbind` or similar, like so. Also `setNames` is needed to avoid duplicated column names.

```
set.seed(42)
for(i in 1:5) {
  output <- sample(names, size=length(names), replace=F)
  df <- setNames(cbind.data.frame(df, output), c(names(df), paste0("output", i)))
}
df
#    names output1 output2 output3 output4 output5
# 1      A       A       8       9       3       5
# 2      B       5       7      10       A       4
# 3      3      10       4       3       B       B
# 4      4       8       A       4       6       8
# 5      5       B       5       5      10       3
# 6      6       4      10       6       8       A
# 7      7       6       B       A       4      10
# 8      8       9       6       B       5       7
# 9      9       7       9       8       7       6
# 10    10       3       3       7       9       9
```

Or, since R is vectorized, better do this w/o loop, because it's faster and more concise:

```
set.seed(42)
R <- 5
cbind(df, `colnames<-`(replicate(R, sample(names)), paste0("output", 1:R)))
#    names output1 output2 output3 output4 output5
# 1      A       A       8       9       3       5
# 2      B       5       7      10       A       4
# 3      3      10       4       3       B       B
# 4      4       8       A       4       6       8
# 5      5       B       5       5      10       3
# 6      6       4      10       6       8       A
# 7      7       6       B       A       4      10
# 8      8       9       6       B       5       7
# 9      9       7       9       8       7       6
# 10    10       3       3       7       9       9
```

*Note:* I use `` `colnames<-` `` here, which is the matrix equivalent of `setNames`. You also could type `cbind(df, setNames(replicate(R, sample(names), simplify=FALSE), paste0("output", 1:R)))`, though, but it's more to type.

Comment: This is way slower than it needs to be jay. How about making the whole df at once using `replicate` or similar and renaming with `setNames(paste(..` etc?

Comment: Sure, already hat that in my clipboard @AllanCameron, for didactic reasons I consider it better to solve the actual issue and provide then an alternative that might be better, you know.

Comment: Sure. I know what you mean - that way the OP finds out what they were doing wrong as well as the correct approach. +1